# make a chat between computer with socket in the Python

Tags: python, server, connection, client, chat

Hello i want to make a chat between two different computer.

Computer Number 1 is server and connected to the Wi-Fi Number 1.

Computer Number 2 is client and connected to the Wi-Fi Number 2.

But my problems is: Computer Number 2 can't connect to the Computer Number 1 it actually for that the Computer Number 2 can't find the server IP.

What should i do?

Comment: We'd need far more information than that. If it's an `OSError`, please post it in full. Also, are you trying to connected to Computer 1 from within the same network, or from external to it? I'm not sure what you mean by "WiFi Number 1/2:.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the broadcast adress to send first message to the server. Then the server would respond to client and establish a connection.